# Dynamic google spreadsheet data to HTML

Tags: html, templates, google-apps-script

Having problems with generating a spreadsheet into a HTML table.  Following this:  [HTML Service- Apps scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service).    It isn't clear to me how to define the variable *htmlOutput* or how to display/return it. Thanks for your thoughts.

```
function doGet() {
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myTemplate');
var htmlOutput =  t.evaluate();
return htmlOutput;
}
```

My HTML template 'myTemplate.html' is:

```
<html>
<table>
<? var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Results-List");
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();  
 var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:G"+lastRow); 
 var data = myRange.getValues();
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { ?>
<tr>
  <? for  (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) { ?>
    <td><?= data[i][j]?></td>
  <? } ?>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I used same code with different spreadsheet and sheet name,it worked fine and displayed the html table without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

*Just a suggestion I didn't put in comments because it needed some advanced formatting...*

You are showing the html template in your example saved as `'myTemplate.html'`, did you name it with an extension or do you show the html extension because it appears so on screen ?

I noticed that if the html file is named `myTemplate.html` or simply `myTemplate` both files are shown the same way in the script editor interface but they are definitely different files. This *could* be a source of error.

To make things a bit more clear, here are 2 screen captures that illustrate :
[image]

[image]

As you can see, both files shows identical in the left column although they are named differently.
Personally I don't add extensions to the html files since the environment identifies the file type automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the input, both of you.  The file name wasn't the issue.

I actually don't get any errors, it seems to run, but nothing is displayed.  I also tried a 2nd method, but it didn't like the syntax of the _spreadsheet.show_ method as shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to work.  Hope this helps others:  (note that *return* was not needed.)

```
function doGet() {
var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myTemplate');
var htmlOutput =  t.evaluate();
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
doc.show(htmlOutput);
}
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that you where trying to show this UI from within a spreadsheet... Functions starting with do get are usually intended to be used as standalone apps or in site pages, that's why nobody could give an appropriate answer. You should read the [documentation on that matter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#DeployingWeb)